# How to display the each value in author attributes

Tags: author-number

I am using xkeyvalue and authblk style files. I have a two **corresponding author address** and **email id** implement in tex file. But I am getting last in first output concept is executed. Last corresponding author address output only displayed. Previous corresponding author address is hide.

My required output below mentioned here:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xparse}%


\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
\vbox to \textheight{\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{12pc}%\vfill%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
{\@correspondence\par}%
    \vskip 6pt%
{\@presentaddress}%
\end{minipage}}}
\hspace*{11pc}
\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-44pc}%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{25pc}
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\raggedright\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}


\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
  \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
    \raggedright  #1\FrontKVMacroEmail%
    }}

\def\@presentaddress{}
\def\presentaddress#1{%
     \gdef\@presentaddress{\textbf{\textit{$\dagger$presentaddress:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}



\define@key{authorinfo}{aff}{%
\def\FrontKVMacroAff{#1}%
}%


\define@key{authorinfo}{coraddress}{%
\def\FrontKVMacroCorAddress{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{email}{%
\def\FrontKVMacroEmail{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{presentaddress}{%
\def\FrontKVMacroPresentAddress{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{link}{%
\def\FrontKVMacroLink{#1}%
}%


\let\OriginalAuthor\author

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{+O{}+m}{%
\setkeys{authorinfo}{#1}%
\ifdef{\FrontKVMacroAff}{%
  \ifdef{\FrontKVMacroLink}{%
    \OriginalAuthor[\FrontKVMacroAff]{\href{\FrontKVMacroLink}{#2}}%
  }{%
    \OriginalAuthor[\FrontKVMacroAff]{#2}%
  }%
}{%
  \ifdef{\FrontKVMacroLink}{%
    \OriginalAuthor{\href{\FrontKVMacroLink}{#2}}%
  }{%
    \OriginalAuthor{#2}%
  }%
}%
\ifdef{\FrontKVMacroCorAddress}{%
  \correspondence{\FrontKVMacroCorAddress}%
}{%
}
\ifdef{\FrontKVMacroPresentAddress}{%
  \presentaddress{\FrontKVMacroPresentAddress}%
}{%
}%
\undef\FrontKVMacroAff%
}% End of RenewDocumentCommand.


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development}
\author[aff={1}]{Maria Luisa Di Vona}
\author{Emanuela Sgreccia}
\author[aff={1,2},coraddress={\textbf{Riccardo Narducci},\break Dipartimento di Scienze e
Tecnologie Chimiche, Universita di Roma Tor Vergata, Via della
Ricerca Scientifica 1, 00133 Roma,Italia},email={Narducci117@gmail.com}]{Riccardo Narducci}
\author[aff={1,2},link={http://people/u/186791},coraddress={\textbf{Luca Pasquini}, Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK},email={LucaPasquini1215@gmail.com}]{Luca Pasquini}
\author[aff={3},link={http://people/u/78814}]{Hongying Hou}
\author[aff={2},link={http://people/u/128850}]{Philippe Knauth}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

My Current output below mentioned here:

[image]

The two corresponding author and email address should be displayed as per my required output. How to achieve this goal?. Please advice

Comment: Usually articles have only one corresponding author - it indicates the person who submitted the article.

Comment: @Andrew Swann In such cases two corresponding authors contributed one article. I mentioned my required two corresponding author output.